# Test $x_n = (n+i\pi)^n n^{-n + 1/n}$ for convergence and give its limit if possible.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Test $x_n = (n+i\pi)^n n^{-n + 1/n}$ for convergence and give its limit if possible.

---

I'm not really sure what to do here. My first instinct was to rewrite the sequence as $x_n= (n+i\pi)^n n^{-n} n^{1/n}$ and evaluate the limits, but I'm left with $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n^{1/n}=1$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n^{-n}=0$, which leaves me with nothing really. Can somebody help out?

Answer (score 2):

In my usual naive way,

$\begin{array}\\
x_n 
&= (n+i\pi)^n n^{-n + 1/n}\\
&= (1+i\pi/n)^n n^{1/n}\\
&\to e^{\pi i}
\qquad\text{since }(1+x/n)^n \to e^x
\text{ and } n^{1/n} \to 1\\
&=-1\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Ouf thanks, I was totally blind towards that